# Xcode: Ongoing message. The document had an issue that was found and repaired

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I get an ongoing message for all my storyboards saying:

The document “   .storyboard” had an issue that was found and repaired.

This may be due to an SCM operation such as merging. Please save the document to fix the issue.

Multiple resources have the same name: scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor.
(and some more resources)

I already deleted all derived data, clean builded etc. but it doesn't change anything. Even when saving the files it pops up again and again.

I couldn't found any solution for this problem.

Maybe someone of you can tell me what's wrong!
What I can say is that I have multiple backups which I also open once in a while with the same name.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Are you using Git or some other version control system? You can try checking out older commits to see what change introduced the problem.

Comment: What changed is Xcode. This is a new warning. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344102/xcode-shows-the-document-had-4-issues-that-were-found-and-repaired-multiple-re