# Xcode shows "The document had 4 issues that were found and repaired./Multiple resources have the same name: groupTableViewBackgroundColor." alert

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode12

If I open one of the storyboards in my Xcode project, I get this alert:

[image: "The document [storyboard name] had 4 issues that were found and repaired." error alert]

> The document [storyboard name] had 4 issues that were found and repaired.
>
> This may be due to an SCM operation such as merging. Please save the document to fix the issues.

> Multiple resources have the same name: groupTableViewBackgroundColor.

I tried saving the document, but the error kept popping up.

What is this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error looks like to be an Xcode bug, as I cannot recall having merge issues with my storyboard. It can be fixed by editing the storyboard's source code. Here's how you can do it:

- Right click on your storyboard in the Project navigator and select **Open As/Source Code**.

[image: Open As/Source Code]

- Search for the following term in the file by pressing Cmd+F:

  `<systemColor name="groupTableViewBackgroundColor">`
- Delete all instances. I've had 5 color instances named `groupTableViewBackgroundColor` for some reason. Since storyboards are XML-based, the definitions end with `</systemColor>`:

  ```
  <systemColor name="groupTableViewBackgroundColor">
      <color red="0.94901960784313721" green="0.94901960784313721" blue="0.96862745098039216" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
  </systemColor>
  ```
- Right click again on the file, select **Open As/Interface Builder - Storyboard** and the error should go away.

If the error still persists, **delete and re-add the storyboard file**.

Comment: Excellent answer. Spot on. Thanks!

Comment: It works, but as you have noticed already, the error comes back after a while. I ended up removing all references to groupTableViewBackgroundColor and darkTextColor from the Storyboard and work around it.

Comment: @MarioHuizinga I've edited my answer. It looks like you should delete *all* instances of the groupTableViewBackgroundColor systemColor definition.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! However I deleted all but one, and so far the the error didn't come back.